# How do i get the time of dataframe execution on the python prompt linux

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

how to calculate pandas dataframe execution time on the python prompt linux, i importing timeit and using the same but did not get it..

```
>>> timeit ; df.groupby('A').filter(lambda g: len(g) > 1).drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B'], keep="first")
<module 'timeit' from '/usr/lib/python3.6/timeit.py'>
     A      B  C   D
1  foo    one  0   0
3  foo    two  4   8
5  bar   four  6  12
6  bar  three  7  14
```

What i did as follows but wondering if that's the correct way ..

```
>>> import time
>>> start_time = time.time()
>>> print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time),  df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B'], keep="first"))
--- 43.261765003204346 seconds ---      A      B  C   D
1  foo    one  0   0
3  foo    two  4   8
4  cat    one  8   4
5  bar   four  6  12
6  bar  three  7  14
```

OR..

```
>>> import timeit
>>> print(timeit.timeit(),'\n', df.groupby('A').filter(lambda g: len(g) > 1).drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B'], keep="first"))
0.007132536033168435
      A      B  C   D
1  foo    one  0   0
3  foo    two  4   8
5  bar   four  6  12
6  bar  three  7  14
```

Is this the correct way.

Comment: llinux has a  ```time``` function for that. I  guess u'll have to put ur code in a .py file and run it with time

Comment: @sammywemmy,  i'm just trying to see how we can use that on the python prompt for a quick .

Comment: if that's the case then run ipython instead. u can run timeit from the ipython prompt

Comment: Please [read the documentation of `timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/timeit.html#module-timeit)

Comment: @ForceBru, i am reading through but unable to get it translated to my use, trying to understand yet..

Answer (score 0):

We import a default python **packages** datetime. The variable **now** save the hour before execute the dataframe commands. After excute the command of the dataframe we see again the hour and we save the difference in the variable **time_execution**.

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

#dataframe


time_execution = datetime.now() -now
print(time_execution)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Okey, i give some more information but i think it is easy to see what happends.